# Is it expensive to use spread operator on JavaScript Sets to access methods from Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

First of all, it is highly frustrating that JavaScript's Set does not implement many useful methods from Array and I often avoid sets because of that.

That being said, is it expensive to use the spread operator just to access methods from Array? Is there any more efficient option (e.g., some library)? I have in mind cases like this:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(company,colleaguesArray) {
    this.worksAt = null;
    this.worksWith = colleagues;
  }

  areColleaguesOnTheSameCompany() {
    return this.worksWith.every(colleague => 
      this.worksAt === colleague.worksWith);
  }

  getColleaguesWorkplaces() {
    return this.worksWith.reduce((acc,colleague) =>
      acc.add(colleague.worksAt), new Set())
  }
}
```

I believe it would be best to use a set for `worksWith`. However, as my API of Person grows I would need to constantly change it back into an array to use map/reduce/every/some... and so on. Remember that`Person` can be part of a large library and have dozens of functions itself, this is only a trivial example.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with a set where you need to use (apparently many?) array methods? Can't you use an array and then collect into a set in the end?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. I already collect the return into sets to avoid duplicates, but that does not prevent other developers from messing up the object when editing arrays directly instead of using proper functions (in the example, people should not duplicate elements in the `worksWith`  array).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of being "expensive" It's a linear O(n) operation to spread elements.

Perhaps a `Set` is not the data structure you need if your constantly turning it back and forth?

Comment: I tried to clarify what I have in mind, but you are right it is not "expensive". Maybe it is just annoying to write `[...someSet]` whenever I want to use Array functions. Still I would be happy to have a more elegant library for sets.